# Finding a substring despite lowecases and upper cases in python

Tags: python, string

Assume I have the following string:

```
mystring = "my eMaIL address is example@example.com"
```

I would like to be able to find its position on the string. I know that if I use this, I will get it.

```
pos = mystring.find("eMaIL")
```

But I was wondering if it's possible to get the same result using:

```
pos = mystring.find ("email")
```

Thank you all :)

Comment: `mystring.lower().find("email")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.lower()` like this:

```
pos = mystring.lower().find ("email")
```